# Nonstandard dual parametrization of graph problems

Tags: reference-request, graph-algorithms, fixed-parameter-tractable

One fundamental result in parameterized complexity of graph problems is that VERTEX COVER parameterized by the solution size $k$ is fixed-parameter-tractable (FPT). On the other hand, when parameterized by the "dual parameter" $|V(G)|-k$, it becomes equivalent to INDEPENDENT SET parameterized by solution size (because any vertex cover is the complement of an independent set), and thus it is W[1]-hard.

Although this seems less natural, I am interested in the parameterized complexity of VERTEX COVER for the parameter $|E(G)|-k$. This is a larger parameter than $|V(G)|-k$. Is VERTEX COVER FPT for this parameter?

***Note:** I am also interested in similar parameterizations for other graph problems (e.g. DOMINATING SET). The only place where I have seen both kinds of dual parameters studied is for the **hypergraph** problem TEST COVER in the 2012 paper "[Parameterized Study of the Test Cover Problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-32589-2_27)" by Crowston, Gutin, Jones, Saurabh and Yeo. (also [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0117))*

**Edit (04/12/2016):** This parameterization is also studied for the other hypergraph problem HITTING SET in the 2011 paper [Kernels for below-upper-bound parameterizations of the hitting set and
directed dominating set problems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397511005378) by Gutin, Mones and Yeo ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5881)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n:=|V(G)|$ and $m:= |E(G)|$. The dual parameter $m-k$ is always at least as large as $m-n$ which in turn is at least as large as the size of a feedback edge set, a set of edges whose removal makes $G$ acyclic.

The size of a smallest feedback edge set, let's call it feedback edge number $\phi$, is also at least as large as the feedback vertex number and the treewidth of the graph. This directly implies that Vertex Cover is fixed-parameter tractable for $m-k$. Moreover, it has a polynomial kernel since Vertex Cover parameterized by feedback vertex number has one (this was shown by Jansen and Bodlaender in Vertex Cover Kernelization Revisited - Upper and Lower Bounds for a Refined Parameter. Theory Comput. Syst. 53(2): 263-299 (2013), http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00224-012-9393-4).

A simple direct linear kernel for Vertex Cover parameterized by feedback edge number $\phi$ should be obtainable as follows: Remove all degree-0 vertices, add the neighbor of any degree-1 vertex to the vertex cover, and reduce paths of degree-2 vertices that contain at least 2 vertices (decreasing the bound on $k$ accordingly). After exhaustive application of these reduction rules, in the resulting graph $n=O(\phi)$. This directly implies a kernel for the larger parameter $m-k$.

To answer your question for references: I would look for feedback edge number which is smaller than the dual parameter $m-k$, has been considered in the literature, and often gives fixed-parameter tractability results also for Dominating Set (as the parameter is quite large). Here are three further examples:

Johannes Uhlmann, Mathias Weller:
Two-Layer Planarization parameterized by feedback edge set. Theor. Comput. Sci. 494: 99-111 (2013), http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2013.01.029

André Nichterlein, Rolf Niedermeier, Johannes Uhlmann, Mathias Weller:
On tractable cases of Target Set Selection. Social Netw. Analys. Mining 3(2): 233-256 (2013), http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13278-012-0067-7

Sepp Hartung, Christian Komusiewicz, André Nichterlein:
Parameterized Algorithmics and Computational Experiments for Finding 2-Clubs. J. Graph Algorithms Appl. 19(1): 155-190 (2015), http://dx.doi.org/10.7155/jgaa.00352

Comment: If there are any, then "Remove all degree-0 vertices" decreases n without changing m, so increases m-n. ​ Accordingly, the resulting graph's size being linear in the _resulting_ graph's parameter does not mean the resulting graph's size has any bound in terms of the _input_ graph's parameter. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I changed this part to a kernelization for the feedback edge number which is smaller.

Comment: Subsidiary question: the 2 papers I pointed to were for hypergraph problems, but there $m-k$ is not necessary larger than $n-k$ since there can less hyperedges than vertices. Is there soem generic trick that works there?

Answer (score 9):

I think this problem is FPT. Suppose that the graph contains a path on $2k+1$ vertices. Then, I claim the answer is YES: we select the second, fourth, sixth, etc. vertices of this path in a solution and remove them from the graph. We now have a graph $G'$ with $|E(G')|\le |E(G)|-2k$. It is easy to find a vertex cover of $G'$ with size at most $|E(G')|$. Together with the removed vertices this gives a vertex cover of size at most $|E(G)|-k$ for $G$.

If the graph does not contain a path on $2k+1$ vertices, then a DFS tree of the graph has height at most $2k+1$, and hence can be used to construct a tree decomposition of width at most $2k$. We can then solve Vertex Cover optimally with the standard algorithm for treewidth.

Comment: Thanks, neat! If you know a reference where such parameter is studied (for other graph problems), please let me know.